# Linking to specific mui-tab using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a set of tabs using material ui as the base. I want to be able to link to one of the tabs so that that tab is open when landing on the page. All very simple for me outside of the react application(add anchor).
I've searched for solutions but no good, I suspect I need to do something with the main router and path and pass a property that tells the tab which one to be open. Then simply add that property on the link to pass to the page?

I will link to the tab(from a different page) using `<Link>`

```
<Link to="/page/tabpage" title="Link to tab 2">Link to tab 2</Link>
```

I imagine I will need to pass a value from this link to the URL which then opens up that specific tab, something like:

```
<Link to="/page/tabpage#tab2" title="Link to tab 2">Link to tab 2</Link>
```

My app route path for this page looks like this:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Route path={`${match.url}/page/tabpage`}
        component={asyncComponent(() => import('./routes/tabpage'))} />
```

The tabpage looks like something like the following:(for the general idea)

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Tabs, { Tab } from "material-ui/Tabs";
import { whenGapiReady } from "../../../util/gapiHelper";

function TabContainer({ children, dir, className }) {
  return (
    <div dir={dir} className={className} style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  dir: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

class tabpage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    whenGapiReady(() => {});
  }
  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs
          initialSelectedIndex={this.state.value}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          fullWidth
          scrollable
          scrollButtons="on"
          classes={{ root: styles.root }}
        >
          <Tab className="tab" label="Tab 1" />
          <Tab className="tab" label="Tab 2" />
        </Tabs>

        <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>TAB 1 CONTENT ECT..</TabContainer>
        <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>TAB 2 CONTENT ECT..</TabContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({}) => {};

export default tabpage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with redux or local storage to manage active tabs and their content.

Map your tabs and render links.

Then render different components in different routes with links matched paths.

You may find some of my code usefull: https://github.com/SimonMulquin/EventsPlanning/tree/master/client/src/ui